# Informatica - SQL query to extract data from JSON format value

Tags: informatica

My source is Oracle table 'SAMPLE' which contain the JSON value in the column REF_VALUE which becomes as a source in Informatica mapping. The data looks as below

## PROPERTY    |   REF_VALUE

CTMappings        |      {CTMappings": [
{"CTId":"ABCDEFGHI_T2","EG":"ILTS","Type":"K1J10200"},
{"CTId":"JKLMNOPQR_T1","EG":"LAM","Type":"K1J10200"}
"}]}"

I have the SQL query to explore the JSON Data into rows as below

select
substr(CTId,1,9) as ID,
substr(CTId,9,11) as VERSION,
type as INTR_TYP,
eg as ENTY_ID,

from
(
select jt.*
from SAMPLE,
JSON_TABLE (ref_value, '$.Mappings[*]'
columns (
CTId varchar2(50) path '$.formId',
eg varchar2(50) path '$.eg',
type varchar2(50) path '$.Type'
)) jt
where trim(pref_property) = 'Ellipse.Integration.FSM.FormMappings')

The result of table as below
CTiD          VERSION   EG  Typ
========      =======   ====    ======
ABCDEFGHI   T2  ILTS    K1J102001
KLMNOPQR    T1  LAM K1J102000

which is required as an output ( JSON into rows)

Im new to Informatica so I have used source table as 'SAMPLE' and further I want to use this query to extract the data into row format in Informatica but I dont know how to proceed. I have the image please refer

[image]

If anyone answers quickly, it will be a great help

Answer (score 0):

Declare the fields in `Source Qualifier` and use `SQL Override` property to place your query - that should do the trick.